# Converting String^ to Int

Tags: .net, string, type-conversion, int, c++-cli

I have no trouble programming in VB but I'm having a *very* hard time getting the hang of C++.

I have variables...

```
newData = gcnew String(nonSharedRXBuffer, 0, newBytesReceived);
myString = newData;
String^ tempString;
unsigned int Value;
```

and parts of code....

```
tempString = newData->Remove(1,(newData->Length)-1);
Value = tempString;  **//need to convert the String^ to Int**
newData = newData->Remove(0, 1);
tempString = newData->Remove(1,(newData->Length)-1);
Value = tempString;  **//need to convert the String^ to Int**
newData = newData->Remove(0, 1);
```

How do I convert `tempString` (which is a `String^`) into an `Int`?

Answer (score 0):

Standard 'learning the language' warning: This isn't C++ you're writing, it's C++/CLI. C++/CLI is a language from Microsoft intended to allow C# or other .Net languages to interface with unmanaged C++. In that scenario, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. If you're still learning C++, please do *not* start with C++/CLI. In order to effectively write in C++/CLI, one should already know both C++ and C#, and then there's still things to learn about C++/CLI. If you want to learn C++, stick with unmanaged C++. (In Visual Studio, create a "Win32" C++ project.) If you want to learn managed code, then I would use C#.

---

That said: [`Int32::TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) is how you convert from a .Net `String^` to an integer.

```
String^ tempString = ...;
int value;

bool converted = Int32:::TryParse(tempString, value);
if (!converted)
{
    // tempString did not contain a valid integer. Handle the error.
}
```